# MVVM Question about default values in combo boxes

Tags: mvvm

I have a combo box on a view that will have a default of "Active" when the form is loaded. Whose job is it to set the combobox to "Active", the code behind in the loaded method or the View Model?

Bill

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's the ViewModel's job. There are at least 2 approaches to do it:

- bind the `SelectedItem` of the combo to a property of the ViewModel, and set this property to the value you want
- obtain the default view for the collection (`CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView`) and set the current item with the `MoveCurrentTo` method (don't forget to set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` to true on the `ComboBox`)